# Solubility of EDTA in water

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility

Why is EDTA ($\ce{C10H16N2O8}$) poorly soluble in water?

I am interested in analyzing the hardness of water in a sample due to the presence of $\ce{Ca^2+}$ cations. I attempted to do this by titrating with ethylene diamine tetraacetic acid ($\ce{C10H16N2O8}$) however these attempts have proven to be futile.

Comment: There are all sorts of standard procedures for doing a total water hardness. You can also do Ca only. Did you use a standard procedure (if so which one?), or did you try to make something up?

Comment: I've done EDTA titration of hard water. We did it in the class I used to teach. What procedure are you using? Are you using [EBT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eriochrome_Black_T)? To answer your question, EDTA isn't typically considered poorly soluble in water. I believe more is going on here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran into the same problem myself when I bought (foolishly, it turned out) [$\ce{H4EDTA}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylenediaminetetraacetic_acid) instead of $\ce{Na2H2EDTA}$ or $\ce{Na4EDTA}$ for some of the experiments for my doctorate.  It really confused me, because carboxylic acids are generally quite soluble and, with ***four*** of the things, you'd think it'd dissolve right away.  But, no.  There are even amines in there, too, but they apparently don't help much either.

Based on the abstract of a 1973 article by Ladd and Povey<sup>1</sup>, my guess is the apparent poor solubility of $\ce{H4EDTA}$ is actually a kinetic effect, due to a network of intra- and inter-molecular [hydrogen bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond) present in the solid (emphasis added):

> The [EDTA] molecule exists in a *cis* conformation and possesses two-fold symmetry, the diad axis passing through the central $\ce{C-C}$ bond. **The nitrogen atom is protonated, and takes part in a bifurcated intramolecular hydrogen bond. A short $\mathbf{\left(2.46~Å\right)}$ hydrogen bond links the oxygen atoms of adjacent molecules.**

I don't have the necessary thermodynamic data at hand to argue with certainty, but my guess is that the activation energy for solvent penetration into this hydrogen-bond network is rather high, and thus the rate of solvation is slow even though the overall process is (presumably) [exergonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exergonic_process) $\left(\Delta G < 0\right)$.

**Reference**: Ladd, M. F. C.; Povey, D. C. Crystallographic and spectroscopic studies on ethylenediaminetetraacetic acid (edta). *J. Crystal Molec. Struct.* **1973,** *3* (1), 15–23. [DOI: 10.1007/BF01270899](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01270899).

Comment: An option would be to dissolve EDTA through $\mathrm{pH}$ with an alkaline hydroxide, the cation of which will not form complexes, in effect re-creating $\ce{Na2H2EDTA}$ or $\ce{Na4EDTA}$ *in vitro*. The kinetics aren't great but much better than for the dissolution of the tetravalent acid if I remember correctly.